# Python enums with complex types

Tags: python, enums, complextype

I'm new to Python and I'm wondering if I can build enums with complex structures, not just primitive types. For instance (in pseudo-code):

```
Point::Enum
  x, y
  constructor ( x, y ) {
    ...
  }

  bottom_left = Point ( 0, 0 )
  top_left = Point ( 0, 100 )
  top_right = Point ( 100, 100 )
  bottom_right = Point ( 100, 0 )
```

So far, I could only find Python documentation that mentions enums with strings or ints.

Comment: There is no restriction on type, plus in Python strings and ints are 'complex types'.

Comment: There are no primitive types in Python

Comment: OK, there aren't, yet 1 or 'blah' are rather different than (0,0) :-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want `Point` as a separate entity from the `Enum` that tracks the corners, then you need them to be separate:

```
from enum import Enum

class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point(%r, %r)' % (self.x, self.y)

class Corner(Enum):
    BottomLeft = Point(0, 0)
    TopLeft = Point(0, 100)
    TopRight = Point(100, 100)
    BottmRight = Point(100, 0)
```

Doing it this way means that each `enum` contains a `Point` as its value, but is not a `Point` itself:

```
>>> Corner.BottomLeft
<Corner.BottomLeft: Point(0, 0)>
>>> Corner.BottomLeft.value
Point(0, 0)
```

If you want the `enum` members to *be* a `Point`, then mix in the `Point` class:

```
from enum import Enum

class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point(%r, %r)' % (self.x, self.y)

class Corner(Point, Enum):
    BottomLeft = 0, 0
    TopLeft = 0, 100
    TopRight = 100, 100
    BottmRight = 100, 0

>>> Corner.TopLeft
<Corner.TopLeft: (0, 0)>
>>> isinstance(Corner.TopLeft, Point)
True
>>> Corner.TopLeft.value
(0, 100)
>>> Corner.TopLeft.x
0
>>> Corner.TopLeft.y
100
```

Finally, if all you need is for the `enum`s to have the `x` and `y` attributes:

```
from aenum import Enum

class Corner(Enum):
    __init__ = 'x y'
    BottomLeft = 0, 0
    TopLeft = 0, 100
    TopRight = 100, 100
    BottmRight = 100, 0

>>> Corner.TopLeft
<Corner.TopLeft: (0, 100)>
>>> Corner.TopLeft.value
(0, 100)
>>> Corner.TopLeft.x
0
>>> Corner.TopLeft.y
100
```

Note that that last example is using the [`aenum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) package<sup>1</sup>.  You can accomplish the same thing with either [`enum34`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) or the stdlib `enum` by writing an `__init__` for the `Point` class.

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Enum:
    bottom_left = Point(0, 0)
    top_left = Point(0, 100)
    top_right = Point(100, 100)
    bottom_right = Point(100, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare them as global variables like `BOTTOM_LEFT`, `TOP_LEFT`, `TOP_RIGHT`, `BOTTOM_RIGHT`.

As you might be aware unlike other languages (C++, Java) Python doesn't have, You just declare it and don't change it (Gentleman's game)

Yet Alex Martelli's [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65207-constants-in-python) can come handy to emulate const in Python